# Render partial in different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, renderpartial

I have a Orders controller and in my New.html.haml controller view I'm trying to render the _form partial for address

order new.html.haml

```
= render "/addresses/form"
```

address _form.html.haml

```
= form_for @address do |f|
  - if @address.errors.any?
  #error_explanation
    %h2= "#{pluralize(@address.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this address from being saved:"
    %ul
      - @address.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li= msg

  .field

   # All the form fields

  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

I've been getting the error

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

What would be the best way to fix this? I though of creating a partial just for that but I don't think creating another form partial would be in compliance to DRY.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @address is nil, need to fix that.

Comment: Iceman I do get that... I could probably use Address.new in the form  tag. Are you suggesting to add @address = Address.new in the order/new method?

Comment: @Marrento Ok, I made a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this error is that `@address` is `nil`
To fix you need to instantiate in the controller

```
# orders_controller.rb
def new
  @address = Address.new
end

def edit
  @address = Address.find params[:id]
end
```